# Cassandra How would multiple data columns with compound key be represented?

Tags: cassandra, cql3

I have been reading the CQL3 for Cassandra users blog post and the situation with a compound primary key and a single column not included in the key is pretty well explained. What I would like to know is how data is represented and stored if there is more than one column not in the primary key such as in the example below. Is what I am writing Cassandra nonsense or an anti-pattern?

```
CREATE TABLE subscriptions (
  user_id uuid,
  periodical_id uuid,
  from timestamp,
  until timestamp
  PRIMARY KEY (user_id , periodical_id)
)
```

In this case the subscription has a time bounds that should be kept with the record and I want to look up all of the subscriptions for a user with:

```
SELECT * FROM subscriptions WHERE user_id = :userId
```

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Check my answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/42736609/2320144

Comment: Also you can look it up how it's actually stored by using sstable2json utility https://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/debugging-sstables-in-3-0-with-sstabledump