# Optimization for long primary key in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I am considering using String as a primary key and the String might be quite long (up to 300-400 chars).

I am looking to understand whether there is any optimizations regards the way primary key is saved. Is it saved as part of each row as any other data or is it somehow optimized?
Is the answer different for composite key?

Are there any best practice recommendations regards the length of primary key? The only thing I found is that it is limited to 65KB.

Comment: are you talking about primary key (partition key + clustering columns) or about partition key?

Comment: @AlexOtt To be honest, I can't remember. I wrote "primary key" but your question makes me doubt whether it is correct. I think "partition key" might be more accurate. Also makes sense with the example of single field which is uuid. Note for next time - I should have add the commands I used to create the tables, to make it more clear.

Answer (score 1):

To understand whether there is an optimization I created two tables at Cassandra (using Cassandra3.0 docker).

Both tables had 70,000 entries with uuid as the primary key.

Table A had 70,000 different values of primary key.

Table B had only 7 different primary keys, with 10,000 entries per key.

Flush was performed on both tables using nodetool. Both tables had one SSTable.

**The result:**

According to `nodetool cfstats` the `Space used` field of table A is almost 1,000 times larger than that of table B.

`Bloom filter space used` of table A is about 3,000 times larger than that of table B.

It supports the information I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42736040/calculating-the-size-of-a-table-in-cassandra) (see the formula specified by Jeff Carpenter).

My conclusion is that Cassandra has an optimization that prevents it to save the same primary key over and over.

Answer (score 0):

Your conclusion seems to be right, see here: https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/cassandra/data_modeling/data_modeling_refining.html

It makes sense if you speak of a partition key, as Alex Ott mentioned: If you have 10k rows with the same partition key value, then they end up in the same partition, and it suffices to save the partition key only once, no matter how many rows are in the partition.